# very short-lived idle GAE instance

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm perfectly fine with the fact that an idle instance dies after 15 minutes or so, and need to be loaded upon next request.

But I have an application that dies after less than 5 minutes of inactivity. 
this increases the chances of a load_request AND makes charges me for 15 minutes.

how can I debug this? why it dies so quickly.
my other app dies after 15 minutes of inactivity as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [GAE Pricing](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/billing#time_granularity_instance_pricing)

> Instances are charged for their uptime in addition to a 15-minute
> startup fee, the startup fee covers what it takes for App Engine to
> bring up and down the instance. So, if you have a dynamic instance
> only serving traffic for 5 minutes, you will pay for 5+15 minutes, or
> $0.08 / 60 * 20 = 2.6 cents. Additionally, if the instance stops and
> then starts again within a 15 minute window, the startup fee will only
> be charged once and the instance will be considered "up" for the time
> that passed. For example, if a dynamic instance is serving traffic for
> 5 min, is then down for 4 minutes and then serving traffic for 3 more
> minutes, you will pay for (5+4+3)+15 minutes, or $0.08 / 60 * 27 = 3.6
> cents.

This explains why you are charged and how much exactelly for your situation

Comment: I have no problem with billing.
The question is Why it dies in less than 5 minutes.

Comment: @SabihAgbaria Sorry lost by the last part of your question... Can you see if another request after 5 minutes spawns another instance?

Comment: No problem, I didn't stress that. Yes it does spans another instance.. which responds to a couple of requests then dies after being idle for a couple of minutes.

Comment: @SabihAgbaria the thing is more why your other application's instances live more. It's normal to die after a few mins from the request.

Comment: @SabihAgbaria double confirmed. My instance do not live more than 5 mins as well. And this is normal as I said before.

Comment: You're right. My initial assumption was false...  thanks for you help.